# Use properties of different models in view (.net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I am learning MVC and display a list of products in a view.

```
@model IEnumerable<Domain.Model.Product>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:50px; text-align:left">Id</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Category</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
        </td>            
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The products belong to categories, which are displayed in the right column. I now want to filter the products by categories, for which I would like to use a dropdownlist control. I found @Html.DropDownListFor(), but as far as I understand, this will only give me properties of the currently underlying model (Product).

My controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    ProductRepository pr = new ProductRepository();

    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        List<Product> products = pr.GetAll();

        return View("List", products);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aye, you need to pass more than just product. Some sort of join of Categories and product, ora  new "model" categoryandProduct that holds categories and products and some suitable 'look up' methods maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.  Just create a class with the info that you need.

```
public class ProductsModel 
{
     public ProductsModel() {
          products = new List<Product>();
          categories = new List<SelectListItem>();
     }

     public List<Product> products { get;set; }
     public List<SelectListItem> categories { get;set; }

     public int CategoryID { get;set; }

}
```

Then your controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    ProductRepository pr = new ProductRepository();

    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        ProductsModel model = new ProductsModel();
        model.products = pr.getAll();

        List<Category> categories = pr.getCategories();
        model.categories = (from c in categories select new SelectListItem {
            Text = c.Name,
            Value = c.CategoryID
        }).ToList();

        return View("List", model);
    }
}
```

Finally, your view

```
@model IEnumerable<Domain.Model.ProductsModel>

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.CategoryID, model.categories)

<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:50px; text-align:left">Id</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Category</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.products) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Id
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Category.Name
        </td>            
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! But @model should only be Domain.Model.ProductsModel. What do you need the CategoryID for? When do you set it?

Comment: When you select an item from the drop down list, it stores the value into the Model's CategoryID.  That way when you post back to the server to filter via ajax or regular, the site knows which category you want to filter on.