# How to pass List model to view in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my HomeController I create a model.

```
var model = this._postService.GetPostByParams(...);
return View(model);
```

And I can get the model in View.

```
@model ShowPin.Core.Paging.PagedList<ShowPin.Core.Domain.Posts.Post>

@foreach(var item in Model){
    <li>@Html.RouteLink(item.Title, "Post", new { postId = item.Id})</li> 
}
```

However, in some of my view, I want several model to pass to View . How can I get It.

I have read a lot of articles but I always got errors.

Reference:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Using-Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-M

I try to use `ViewData` but I cannot cast my model to right type.

- [Use properties of different models in view (.net MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730048/use-properties-of-different-models-in-view-net-mvc?rq=1)

I try to use this way. After I create a new model class `repository`.

```
public class Repository
{
    public Repository()
    {

    }
    public IPagedList<Post> cat1 { get;set; }
    public IPagedList<Post> cat2 { get; set; }
}
```

in controller class

```
_repository.cat1 = this._postService.GetPostByParams(...);
_repository.cat2 = this._postService.GetPostByParams(...);
return View(_repository)
```

I cannot get the right data from this model.

I am new to ASP.NET MVC4 and I am confuse about passing complex model to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a ViewModel which maps to each of your Views. In these ViewModels, you can specify multiple Models and use them accordingly in Views.

Comment: Thanks a lot . But I have solved this problem by just add `@model ShowPin.Web.Models.Repository` to view ...

Comment: You might have solved this issue but in the long run you will run into issues if you don't follow the above method. Creating ViewModels makes life very simple.

Comment: Actually, I have add repository model to the view. But I don't know what you mean map to view.

Comment: "Mapping to View" means that for each field in your View you can create a separate property in your ViewModel. So, if you have a View with say DropDownList and Textbox, you'll have two properties with return types as List<> and String. Let me know if you need further help on it